# Mobile redirect code sending to wrong location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why my code is sending desktop browsers to the mobile site. What ever browser I use on the desktop, it sends to mobile site.

I have also tried removing the else statement but no joy, still the same problem.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
  if (isMobile) {
    // User-Agent is IPhone, IPod, IPad, Android or BlackBerry
    document.location.href = 'http://m.domain.co.uk';
  } else {
    document.location.href = 'https://domain.co.uk';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);` is returning `null` instead of `true/false`.

To match regex create a `RegExp` object and use `test()` method over it.

```js
var mobile = new RegExp(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
if(mobile.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  console.log("Mobile");
  // User-Agent is IPhone, IPod, IPad, Android or BlackBerry
}else{
  console.log("Desktop");
  // Any other useragent. 
}
```

The problem with `str.match()` is it returns `null` when match is not found & `array of matches` when a match is found. So, the result can't be handled directly using `if/else`. You need to check the return type using `typeof` and then perform the corresponding operation.

While `RegExp.test()` is pretty straight and return `true/false` depending upon match or not.

Comment: Hi Atul I think the reason is that Firefox developer is reporting as: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G5037b Safari/602.1 ` in the user agent string. How can that be right?

Comment: in Ipad ? or in desktop ? You may be overriding default user-agent by using mobile mode or from developer options.

Comment: On desktop. I cannot see a way to change in settings. I am using v60 aurora

Comment: When i run your code snippet it returns mobile and i am on desktop

Comment: my bad. it was an addon that was causing the problem. many thanks for your help